# jshint doesn't show errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I researched for a solution to this problem on jshint documentation page and through questions in this forum. I didn't see anything that addresses my problem. I have node.js installed as well as sublimelinter and jshint. In my command line I typed npm node.js and npm jshint and saw that they were installed. I followed the instructions from videos I saw on sublimetext tutorials on YouTube. I purposely made errors in my code but jshint doesn't show them. Here is a screenshot of my code.
[image]

And here is the code in sublimetext3 editor.

```
// JavaScript Document
 var image = document.getElementById('myCities');

 var imageArray =    ['photos/photo1.jpg','photos/photo2.jpg','photos/photo3.jpg','photos/photo4.jpg',     'photos/photo5.jpg','photos/photo6.jpg','photos/photo7.jpg'];

 var imageIndex = 0;

 function changeCities(){

myCities.setAttribute('src', imageArray [imageIndex]);
imageIndex++;
if(imageIndex>=imageArray.length){
    imageIndex=[0];
}

 }
 var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeCities, 3000);

 myCities.onclick = function(){
clearInterval(intervalHandle);
 };
function()
foo = name //this is the error:no brackets for the function, variable is     undefined and the semicolon is left out.
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on what I can do to get jshint to work properly.

Comment: Perhaps these are not "errors" as far as jshint is concerned. Don't mistake a linter with a syntax checker or a compiler.

Comment: jshint definitely sees this as an error - `Missing name in function declaration.` and `'function closure expressions' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option).` ... maybe you have some option set

Comment: I think your suggestion may be right. At one time jshint was showing errors, with a question mark in the left column. I must have done something by mistake. Where do I look for 'option set'? Oh, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm wondering, should I uninstall sublimetext3 and reinstall it. Then I would need to go through the whole process of package control, etc. Would that make a difference.

Comment: Two things: check that you don't have a configuration file (`.jshintrc`) somewhere in all directories from your file up to the root (e.g. `Desktop`). This may prevent `jshint` to lint some errors, but this seems quite unlikely.
Then check the console (`View > Show Console`) of sublime to see if there is any error during the whole process.

Comment: I tried editing my environmental variables with the path: C:ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin. Then I tested for js hint on my command line: npm jshint -v and I got this: 3.3.12. When I do npm which jshint, I get npm@3.3.12 c:program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm. In sublimetext console I get Warning: jshint_deactivated, cannot locate 'jshint'

Comment: Is there another type of linter I can use to check for errors in my javascript code? Jshint is not working for me, and I keep taking suggestions and trying them but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: @swydell: Have you tried Eslint? It catches more errors for than Jshint, and it more often points to the exact location (character) where the problem is.